# #pragma warning(disable: 4577) doesn't work in VS2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm disabling the warning C4577 at the top of my C++ file, outsides of any scope:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4577)
```

But I'm still getting a lots of warnings like:

warning C4577: 'noexcept' used with no exception handling mode specified; termination on exception is not guaranteed.

How can I disable the warning only for my file?
Regards,
Christian

Comment: Why not just specify the exception handling mode via a compiler switch?

Comment: @Christian Check whether you have #pragma warning(default:4577) somewhere in the code which could be turning it back on.

Comment: No, there is'nt any pragma which enables the 4577. Just in the last line of the file #pragma pop.